# facing query problem in Mongodb Aggregation by based on ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

> Hi, I'm facing problem with mongodb Aggregation, i'm new to mongoDB
>   how to get the result of this data based on Object Id in mongoDB

**> my input is like this:**

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "latitude" : "17.4451028",
        "longitude" : "78.3866821",
        "trip_data_id" : ObjectId("5dd637131b5313355ce8bfa1"),
        "user_name" : "Eswar"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : {
        "latitude" : "17.4450606",
        "longitude" : "78.3865973",
        "trip_data_id" : ObjectId("5dd637131b5313355ce8bfa1"),
        "user_name" : "Eswar"
    }
}

{
    "_id" : {
        "latitude" : "17.4451156",
        "longitude" : "78.3867887",
        "trip_data_id" : ObjectId("5dd637131b5313355ce8bfa1"),
        "user_name" : "Eswar"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : {
        "latitude" : "17.4451125",
        "longitude" : "78.3866802",
        "trip_data_id" : ObjectId("5dd637131b5313355ce8bfa1"),
        "user_name" : "Eswar"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : {
        "latitude" : "17.4451187",
        "longitude" : "78.3867869",
        "trip_data_id" : ObjectId("5dd637131b5313355ce8bfa2"),
        "user_name" : "Rajesh"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : {
        "latitude" : "17.4450753",
        "longitude" : "78.3866457",
        "trip_data_id" : ObjectId("5dd637131b5313355ce8bfa2"),
        "user_name" : "Rajesh"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : {
        "latitude" : "17.4451005",
        "longitude" : "78.3866823",
        "trip_data_id" : ObjectId("5dd637131b5313355ce8bfa3"),
        "user_name" : "Mahesh"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : {
        "latitude" : "17.4451287",
        "longitude" : "78.386776",
        "trip_data_id" : ObjectId("5dd637131b5313355ce8bfa3"),
        "user_name" : "Mahesh"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : {
        "latitude" : "17.4451171",
        "longitude" : "78.3867479",
        "trip_data_id" : ObjectId("5dd637131b5313355ce8bfa4"),
        "user_name" : "Venky"
    }
},

{
    "_id" : {
        "latitude" : "17.4450556",
        "longitude" : "78.3866078",
        "trip_data_id" : ObjectId("5dd637131b5313355ce8bfa4"),
        "user_name" : "Venky"
    }
}
```

> but i want the response based on matched Object ID , Like this :

```
{
    "Eswar" : [ {
         "latitude" : "17.4451028",
        "longitude" : "78.3866821"
        },
        {
         "latitude" : "17.4450606",
        "longitude" : "78.3865973"
        },
        {
         "latitude" : "17.4451156",
        "longitude" : "78.3867887"
        },
        {
          "latitude" : "17.4451125",
        "longitude" : "78.3866802"
        }]
},
{
    "Rajesh" : [ {
         "latitude" : "17.4451187",
        "longitude" : "78.3867869"
        },
        {
         "latitude" : "17.4450753",
        "longitude" : "78.3866457"
        }]
},
{
    "Mahesh" : [ {
        "latitude" : "17.4451005",
        "longitude" : "78.3866823"
        },
        {
        "latitude" : "17.4451287",
        "longitude" : "78.386776"
        }]
},
{
    "Venky" : [ {
         "latitude" : "17.4451171",
        "longitude" : "78.3867479"
        },
        {
        "latitude" : "17.4450556",
        "longitude" : "78.3866078"
        }]
}
```

> can you please help me, how to build a query for this input based ob
>   matched Object Id in mongodb and i want the response above showing
>   result

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
          // match only relevant documents.
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user_name",
            coordinates: {$push: {longitude: "$longitude", latitude: "$latitude"}}
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: {$arrayToObject: [[{k: "$_id", v: "$coordinates"}]]}
        }
    }
])
```